# How to update the existing field of solr index using java?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a Solr index in a core having 3000 documents.

I want to modify the value of a single field in the entire core based on unique key PaperID.

I'm using the following java code but instead of updating the existing value it adds new documents.

```
if (solrDocument.get("PaperID").equals(solrDocument2.get("PaperID"))) {

    String Mscore = (String) solrDocument.get("ID");
    String ModifyScore = (String) solrDocument.get("Author");

    //solrDocument.setField("ID", ModifyScore);
    //update the field
    System.out.println(Mscore);
    System.out.println(ModifyScore);
    System.out.println(solrDocument2.get("Mscore") + "\n");

    SolrInputDocument sid = new SolrInputDocument();

    Map<String, Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);

    fieldModifier.put("set", ModifyScore);

    sid.setField("ID", fieldModifier);

    //solr.add(sid);
    solr.commit();

}
```

can anyone guide me accordingly...Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't changing anything, since you've commented out the `.add` command. And you have to use the actual ID in the ID field, since Solr won't know what document to update otherwise. The [field you're changing should have the fieldModifier attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183798/solrj-api-for-partial-document-update):

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

Map<String, String> fieldModifier = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Change ModifyScore to the new value, since you're just using the current value now..
fieldModifier.put("set", ModifyScore);

doc.addField("ID", Mscore);
doc.addField("Author", fieldModifier);

solr.add(doc);
solr.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, Now its working by using Unique Key id field. But it misses the first record of the index, also does not print the first record. i don't know where is the problem between solrj and solr.

Comment: That's impossible to say without seeing the code that retrieves solrDocument1 and solrDocument2, but my guess would be that since you're comparing the values of two documents, you're not comparing against anything useful in your first iteration.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh the code is long that is why check your email. I am comparing the ids of both the index and updates the field accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but please do not send questions or details on email unless we have a prior agreement in place. Keep any information related to the question on Stack Overflow, either in the relevant question or as a new question if the original question has been answered.

Comment: the update command now works, but its looking  unstable: 1) missing the first record of the index. 2) delete the Text field from the indexed which has been already index through Tika..                                                        <entity
                    name="documentImport"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text">
<field column="text" name="Text" />

Comment: All fields in a document being update must be set as stored, or if available for the field type, have docValues set. Otherwise the document will lose the value for the field, since it's not available. This is documented under [Field Storage in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-FieldStorage).